# Sharepoint sites asks autherization continous in Safari 8.0.2

Tags: sharepoint-designer, authorization

Sharepoint sites doesn't open in Safari 8.0.2 . It asks authentication continous. 
How can I solve this problem?

Someone adviced to me this :"Change your Form Based Authentication (FBA) to Claims authentication in SharePoint."

It is a complex process. When I do this, does be formed any problem in  exist users profile.

Is there any way for fix?

Comment: you can have a similar behavior when having a local sharepoint and not disabling localloopbackcheck. 
http://blogs.msdn.com/b/richin/archive/2012/02/08/using-powershell-to-disable-loopback-check.aspx